# What could be causing all users to get temp profiles when logging into a Server 2016 Remote Desktop Server?

Tags: windows-server-2016

We've got an issue we're at the end of our tether on. All users, local or on the domain get temp profiles. It used to only affect 2 local admin accounts, and removing the .bak from the `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\` keys solved the problem.

This no longer works, every time it changes it back to .bak and logs into a temp profile.

We've tested this with a brand new local admin account, it doesn't create a folder in `C:\Users` at all, just goes straight into a temp profile.

We've tried deleting all temp profile folders from `C:\Users\` this doesn't help. We've installed updates, restarted a number of times and this doesn't help.

We've run `SFC /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and neither helped.

We've disabled Windows Defender and checked the Event Viewer, all we can see is `Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.`

The server is an Azure VM. It runs some software we will need the software vendor to reinstall if we provision a new server, but it's 1am and we've got to get something working by 7am.

Any help is appreciated.